# Files Synced to iCloud from iPad not available on icloud.com

Tags: ipad, icloud, books

iPad 9.7" 5th Gen. (2017 model) | iPadOS 13.6.1

I have a lot of PDFs stored in Books. I have set up syncing to iCloud (or at least I think I have), such that every time I add a book I see a brief notification which says that the file is being synced. Also, the space in my iCloud drive decreases correspondingly. However when I log into icloud.com and click on Drive, it's empty. This is the only content for which I have used iCloud, so there's nothing else there that takes up space. Could someone please tell me how to locate my files on iCloud?

Comment: How did you setup syncing to iCloud for Books?  Do you have any other device signed in to the same iCloud account that can see these pdf's?  In Files on the the iPad, have you tried searching for the pdf's by name?

Comment: 1. I'm afraid I don't remember the exact steps right now, but I just googled how to sync books to iCloud and found a useful page.

2. No. When I log in to iCloud, I do it from a Windows 10 laptop, but I can't see the files. 

3. Though the Files app, I don't see an entry for Books when I'm in the 'On my iPad' section. When I switch to 'iCloud Drive', it's empty, but it also says 3.62 GB available on iCloud, meaning that there's at least a GB worth of data in iCloud.

Comment: If it helps the following are enabled in Settings -> <Name/Apple ID> -> iCloud:

* Safari
* iCloud Drive
* Books
* Acrobat (this is a very recent addition, I have had the others for much longer)

Comment: I'll use the same numbers you did to make this easier.  1. That's good, it looks like you have it turned on.  2. They might be in a subfolder.  3. In the Files app, pull down slightly to expose the search bar.  Type the name of one of the pdfs and see if it shows up.

Comment: Nope, no relevant sub-folders. A few of the files appear because I transferred them (and them only) to Acrobat, but they're separate copies. None of them point to Books. And within the 'iCloud Drive' section it says "0 items, 3.59 GB available on iCloud".

Comment: Bumping this up.